# Can you depict the photon's EM field?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photons

Light are made of waves in the electromagnetic field, so I wonder what is the shape of that wave. I mean what would be the EM field surrounding a photon in a particular instant?

[Edit]

Or alternatively, how is the (electromagnetic) energy of the photon distributed in space? This would be equivalent to consider a energy density function U(x,y,z) of the photon. Or at least U(x,y) where x is the direction of the photon and y some perpendicular direction. So the density spread in the y direction would give an idea of the "width" of the photon.

More generally and informally, could consider whether the energy of the photon is all in a single point or distributed in some region, or if the energy has a location at all.

Comment: In response to the edit, it's impossible to give a straightforward answer (sorry!). A single photon could have a definite frequency/energy, in which case there is an equal probability to find it anywhere in space (because of the uncertainty principle). A photon can be localized in a small region of space (eg in a laser beam). Or you can measure the position of the photon (eg in a photodector), at the cost of disturbing it or even absorbing it completely. Like asking for the energy density of the EM field, the probability density to find one photon in a given location depends on the situation.

Answer (score 3):

First, the photon is a neutral particle, so it does not source an electromagnetic field the same way an electron does.

Second, a photon with energy $E$ has an associated frequency which you can work out from $E = hf$ (where $h$ is Planck's constant), and wavelength $\lambda = c/f$ (where $c$ is the speed of light). So, **at a very loose level**, you can think of a photon as being somewhat like a small-amplitude wave packet with frequency $f$ and wavelength $\lambda$.

**However**, this picture is in fact a lie. The reason is subtle and quantum mechanical. It turns out it is impossible to simultaneously measure the **number** of photons and the **phase** of the electromagnetic field. There is an uncertainty principle relating phase and number of the electromagnetic field, in a way that is quite analogous to the more famous uncertainty principle relating position and momentum of a particle.

Therefore, if you want to picture one photon (the number is equal to one so we can't know the phase) you have to imagine a wave with a certain wavelength, but kind of smeared out in space so that it has no phase (ie, there is no definite location of the peaks and troughs of the wave). This may sound like utter nonsense, but such is quantum mechanics. [Technical aside: What is really going on is that the photon's state is a superposition over all possible phases.]

For what it is worth, my picture of a photon is a little ball with a wave drawn on it and a color corresponding to that wavelength. I think most physicists give up on having a clear visualization and learn to trust the math.

Comment: -1 for not answering the main question, which is what is a photons E-field. Also, I don't agree with a number of different things in this answer, especially this statement: "I think most physicists give up on having a clear visualization and learn to trust the math."

Comment: OK I'll tap out before we get into some kind of flame war, but all I'll say is that I stand by my answer.

Comment: Just to clarify one point, you are right that I was being glib by "I think most physicists give up on having a clear visualization and learn to trust the math." I don't mean that intuition has no part in physics, but that you have to be very careful which pictures you are using in quantum mechanics. In particular, "Should I visualize a photon as a particle or a wave" is one question I think is correctly answered by "it is a quantum particle, and no analogy perfectly substitutes for doing quantum mechanics to understand what the particle will do."

Comment: @Steven sometimes the only answer is that there is no answer.

Comment: There's somewhat of a tension within the phrase "a wave packet with wavelength $\lambda$". If a wave has a definite wavelength, then it it must be infinitely extended, and if it has finite extent, then it must be a superposition of infinitely many wavelengths. How is this apparent contradiction resolved in QED?

Comment: @tparker You are right, a more precise statement would be "a wave with wavelength $\lambda$ convolved with a Gaussian with standard deviation larger than $\lambda$" or something like this.

Comment: Interesting. So there is a nonzero probability of measuring the wavelength of a single photon to be something different from $c/f$? In other words, can you actually have a single photon of definite frequency with finite spatial extent, or will any photon of finite extent necessarily be in a superposition of different frequencies?

Comment: @tparker A single photon in a momentum (or energy) eigenstate will be spread out over an infinite amount of space. For such a photon you will always measure the same energy, but you can't localize it. In realistic experiments there is of course some localization (the photons are in a laser beam or something), in which case there is some spread in momentum space and you can't say precisely what the energy of the photon is. BUT, the uncertainty in the momentum can be very, very small since the wavelength of the photon is a lot smaller than the size of the beam.

Comment: tl;dr: depends on the photon state.

Comment: Gotcha. So realistically, you'll never see "a photon of frequency $f$"; instead you'll see "a photon that's in a superposition of frequencies within a narrow range around the average frequency $f$" or something like that.

Comment: This has always been confusing to me, because there are multiple pairs of (incompatible) conjugate variables in QED: position and momentum/frequency, phase and photon number, electric and magnetic field. I've never had a good intuition for which of these pairs' wave functions are independent, or what is a minimum set of independent degrees of freedom for fully specifying the state of a quantized electromagnetic field (or even a single-photon state).

Comment: Perhaps the most common basis (complete set of states) for describing the EM field is Fock space. Loosely speaking (ie the best I can do in one crude English sentence), this amounts to associating one eigenstate to each possible photon number count over every spatial and polarization mode of the field. There is a more precise description on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fock_space).

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**

Asking "what does a *photon* look like across space and time?" is easy. More often that not people answer this by saying that a photon is a particle that has a some probability to be found across space and time. This probability wave can in fact be shaped in any kind of way, the only rule for it is that is has to be related to whatever created the photon. (answering like this, of course, doesn't actually answer the question though, as you asked that the e-field of a photon looks like.)

Asking "what does a ***photon's electric field***" look like is a much more difficult question to answer "intuitively".  A single photon has a very unique probability distribution of measuring a certain electric field value, which looks like this:

[image]

The only thing that changes when you move it in time in space is that it gains a global phase of $e^{i (kx- \omega t)}$. But in quantum mechanics the square of the probability is measured, and this term disappears completely. Many argue that the "phase" of a single photon is non-existent or ill-defined because you can't measure it.

**Long answer:**

Photons are quantum mechanical, so to explain why this is the case, you need quantum mechanics.
In my PhD I use a detector that can directly measure the electric field of a photon, and we use it to figure out collect statistics to recover the quantum state of our light. To quote my thesis (which is a work in progress):

> In classical physics, the free electric field is said to have energy:

\begin{equation}
    u_{EM} \propto  E^2 + c^2 B^2 \end{equation}

> This looks remarkably similar to the energy of a harmonic oscillator,
> which has the form:

\begin{equation}
    u_{HO} =  \frac{1}{2m} p^2 + m \omega^2 x^2 \end{equation}

> so in the case of the $\frac{1}{2m} = 1$ and $c^2 = m \omega^2$, these
> two equations look remarkably similar:

\begin{align*} H_{EM} &=   E^2 + c^2 B^2 \\
    H_{HO} &=   p^2 + c^2 x^2  \end{align*}

> If [E, B] = $i \hbar$, then these two systems are compeletely
> isomorphic. This would mean that all our understanding of how
> particles in harmonic oscillator potentials behave could be directly
> mapped to this new problem with $x \rightarrow B$ and  $p \rightarrow
> > E$.  In the same way that position and momentum become ``conjugate
> variables," the electric and magnetic can loosely be thought to be
> conjugate variables.
>
> The energy eigenstates have the form:
> $$H|n\rangle=\left(N+\frac{1}{2}\right) \hbar \omega|n\rangle$$
>
> Now normally to find the energy eigenfunctions we project our states
> in the position basis $\langle x |n \rangle =  \psi_n(x)$. But with
> our substitution that $x \rightarrow B$, this becomes: $\langle B |n
> \rangle =  \psi_n(B)$.  Meaning that the value of the amplitude of the
> magnetic field is a quantum operator equivalent to the position of a
> harmonic oscillator. The electric field is generally more interesting
> for us, and we identify that with $p \rightarrow E$, this becomes:
> $\langle E |n \rangle =  \psi_n(E)$. So we can immediately look at the
> energy eigenfunctions for the (which is equivalent to the ``momentum
> quadrature'') harmonic oscillator:

\begin{align}
    \psi_{n}(p)&=\frac{1}{(\pi \hbar m \omega)^{1 / 4}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^{n} n !}} H_{n}\left(\frac{p}{\sqrt{\hbar m \omega}}\right) e^{-p^{2} / 2 \hbar m \omega} \nonumber \\
    \therefore \psi_{n}(E)&=\frac{1}{(\pi \hbar m \omega)^{1 / 4}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^{n} n !}} H_{n}\left(\frac{E}{\sqrt{\hbar m \omega}}\right) e^{-E^{2} / 2 \hbar m \omega} \nonumber \\ \label{hermiteE} \end{align}

> ...
>
> While the E-field of the vacuum being a Gaussian distribution probably
> isn't very suprising, the E-field distribution of a single photon
> might be.
>
> This probability distribution is very unique, as compared to the
> vacuum state. We will see very soon that by measuring the E-field of
> our quantum light, if the light follows this distribution, we can
> conclude that our states are pure single photons (the Fock state,
> $|1\rangle$). As seen in figure 1.4, while the
> probability of measuring $E = 0$ is exactly zero, the average value of
> the E-field is exactly zero ($\langle E \rangle = 0$).

Basically, in summary, a "single photon" is a very special state that has this very specific probability distribution of measuring the value of the electric field. Experimentally, photons are sent into a special detector that can measure the electric field directly (unlike normal detectors which would measure energy/photon Number).

Now if you're wondering how this actually reproduces classical waves..that's a good question. The average value of the e-field of **any** state with a well-defined photon number state is actually zero.

Copying and pasting more stuff I've wrote:

> A photon number state of
> $|1000\rangle$ has zero average value of the electric field. You
> couldn't push an ion even with the electric field of a
> $|10^{10000}\rangle$ photon state! (Of course, such a large state
> would likely probably push your ion very far, but you wouldn't be able
> to tell which direction it would move in.)
>
> So, if an infinite numbered Fock  state can't produce a nonzero $\langle E\rangle$, how does classical light even exist? The answer, believe it
> or not, is quantum superposition. When light is in a quantum
> superpositions of different
> Fock states, then it can produce light with a non-zero  $\langle E \rangle$. For example consider the superposition $|\psi \rangle = c_0|0\rangle + c_1|1\rangle$:

\begin{align*}    \langle \psi | E |\psi \rangle &= \Big( \langle0|c_0^* + \langle 1|c_1^* \Big) E \Big(c_0|0\rangle + c_1|1\rangle \Big) \\
    &= |c_0|^2\langle0|E |0\rangle + c_1^*c_0\langle 1| E |0\rangle+ c_0^*c_1\langle 0| E |1\rangle + |c_1|^2\langle1|E |1\rangle \\
    &= c_1^*c_0\langle 1| E |0\rangle+ c_0^*c_1\langle 0| E |1\rangle \end{align*}

> where we identify that the    $\langle0|E |0\rangle$ and $\langle1|E |1\rangle$ terms disappear as discussed earlier.
>
> The easiest way to work out $\langle 0| E |1\rangle$ is to write the
> E-field operator in terms of a and $a^\dagger.$ The annhilation and
> creation operators are the same as in the Harmonic Oscillator (again,
> with the substitutions $B, E \rightarrow X, P$):

\begin{align*} \hat{a} &=\sqrt{\frac{m \omega}{2 \hbar}} \hat{B}+\frac{i}{\sqrt{2 m \omega \hbar}} \hat{E} \\ \hat{a}^{\dagger} &=\sqrt{\frac{m \omega}{2 \hbar}} \hat{B}-\frac{i}{\sqrt{2 m \omega \hbar}} \hat{E} \end{align*}

> inverting this transformation:

\begin{align*} B &=\sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{2 m \omega}}\left(a+a^{\dagger}\right) \\ E &=-i \sqrt{\frac{m \hbar \omega}{2}}\left(a-a^{\dagger}\right) \end{align*}

> which indicates allows us to easily solve for $\langle E \rangle$:

\begin{align*}
    \langle \psi | E |\psi \rangle &= 2\sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{2 m \omega}} ( c_1^*c_0 + c_0^*c_1) \\
    &= 2\sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{2 m \omega}} ( |c_1||c_0| e^{-i( \phi_1-\phi_0)} + |c_0||c_1| e^{i(\phi_1-\phi_0)}) \\
    &= 2\sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{2 m \omega}} ( |c_0| |c_1| \cos{\Delta\phi}) \end{align*}

> where we have written our coefficients in a complex form, such that
> $c_0 = |c_0|e^{i \phi_0}$ and $c_1 = |c_1|e^{i \phi_1}$ and $\Delta \phi = \phi_1 - \phi_0 $.

Things are already a bit long here, but at this point you can see that you get a nonzero mean E-field for certain values of $\phi$. This phase evolves in time proportional to its energy $e^{i \hbar \omega t}.$ This is how you can get classical-like light. To get perfectly classical-looking light, you need a "coherent state" which is an infinite superposition of this energy states. I can work out more if you're interested but this answer is already very long.

Comment: Sorry since you called me out I can't avoid commenting :) I interpret the original question as being: what is the electromagnetic field as a function of spacetime coordinates in a single photon state. While I used basic language I think my answer is correct: you can't really draw a unique electromagnetic field, the photon is a superposition state of field configurations. In fact that is also what you are saying by giving an expression for $\psi(E)$, but you don't give any sense of how different spacetime points are correlated.

Comment: "I interpret the original question as being: what is the electromagnetic field as a function of spacetime coordinates in a single photon state."
Okay, and you can specify that function exactly, so I don't see the point in saying that it is not "unique". A single photon state has a very specific and well-defined wavefunction $\Psi (E)$. I answered at the end how this extends in time, and while I can add how it extends in space - the answer was already a bit long so I cut it short.

Comment: OK but this is a quantum superposition state over field values, and so it's not a straightforward classical field configuration. This is the point I wanted to emphasize, since I interpreted the OP as someone who may not have had a quantum mechanics course. I really doubt that we disagree on anything substantive.

Comment: I do not think this answer provides any intuitive picture for the fields as I think the OP asked for.  Also you move from using $E$ for energy to (apparently) using it for the electric field and this does not help with the clarity of your answer.

Comment: I was looking over this answer again, and I have two friendly comments. The first is that I am not 100% sure that the analogy between the SHO and EM field is as simple as what is stated here. As you say, there is a simple relationship *if* the electric and magnetic fields satisfy $[E,B]=i\hbar$, but in fact the true relationship is more complicated, $[E_i(x),B_j(y)]=i \hbar \epsilon_{ijk} \partial_k \delta^3(x-y)$. Second, I think it's confusing for $m$ to appear in the wavefunction for the field $\psi(E)$, since $m$ has no physical meaning in this context.

Comment: @Andrew, in a more traditional treatment it is the vector potential and the E-field that is used, but I find the B-field to be way more intuitive, since it's something much more familiar. You can find a complete 2nd quantization treatment that treats the B-field [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/nuclear-engineering/22-51-quantum-theory-of-radiation-interactions-fall-2012/lecture-notes/MIT22_51F12_Ch10.pdf)  And you can see that $E \propto a + a^\dagger$ and $B \propto a - a^\dagger$

Comment: Sounds good. My main point is just make sure you can back up $[E,B]=i\hbar$ since you use this at a crucial step in your argument. I personally have never seen this version of the field commutation relations before, but of course that doesn't mean it is not true.