# Is $[E_i(x), B_j(y)]=i \hbar \varepsilon_{ijk}\partial_k \delta^3(x-y) $ ? (and how to derive it?)

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, commutator

In a [comment](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/590705/), user @Andrew says that $$[E_i(x), B_j(y)]=i \hbar \varepsilon_{ijk}\partial_k \delta^3(x-y). $$

Is this the case?

Considering one of Maxwell's equations can be written:

$$\nabla \times \mathbf{E}=-\frac{\partial \mathbf{B}}{\partial t}$$

And the curl can be written products [can be written in this form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol):

$$(\nabla \times \mathbf{F})^{i}(\mathbf{x})=\varepsilon^{i j k} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{j}} F_{k}(\mathbf{x})$$

But I don't see exactly how to put them together.

Comment: I have not checked whether this commutation relation is correct as written. However, it would be a result of the canonical formalism in quantum field theory. Commutation relations in QM do not follow from the equations of motion, so Maxwell's equations will not enter the picture here.

Comment: @RichardMyers, seems like its involved considering the form.

Comment: It is not something I care to work out at any rate. The procedure would be to take the canonical commutation relations between the vector potential and its conjugate momenta (though there is some degeneracy involved due to gauge invariance which might cause complications) then define $E$ and $B$ in terms of the vector potential as you normally would. From there the calculation would be a straightforward commutator algebra computation.

Answer (score 4):

Those equations you write are not going to help you.

The fields do satisfy them, however, as the comments hinted at, the commutator you are looking at comes from the canonical field quantisation of electromagnetism (QED), pedagogically derived for example [here](http://www.quantum.physik.uni-potsdam.de/teaching/ws2011/qo1/script-ch23.pdf).

Start with the gauge field (vector field here) $\mathbf{A}$, and find the canonical momentum from the Lagrangian density $\mathcal{L}$:
$$ \boldsymbol{\Pi} = \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial\dot{\mathbf{A}}}.$$

Calculate the Poisson bracket $\{ A_i(x), \Pi_j(y) \}$ (classical field theory) and then quantise it to a commutator (quantum field theory) and get to:

$$ \left [\hat A_i (x), \hat \Pi_j(y) \right ] = \mathrm{i}  \hbar \delta_{ij}(x-y),$$

where $\hat A$ is now a quantum field operator.

Then, after quantising $E_i(x)$ and $B_j(y)$ and writing them in terms of $\hat A_i$ and $\hat \Pi_j$ you'll get to your desired expression:
$$ [\hat E_i(x), \hat B_j(y)] = \mathrm{i}\frac{\hbar}{\epsilon_0} \varepsilon_{ijk} \partial_k (x-y). $$